# Single vs Multiple @KafkaListener methods for Multiple Topics

Tags: spring-kafka

We are creating a spring-kafka app that listens to multiple topics. What is the difference between having a single method with a @KafkaListener annotation for multiple topics vs having multiple methods with @KafkaListener annotation for each topic? Any benefit of doing it one way vs the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the concurrency, and your requirements.

Let's say each topic has 10 partitions and you have concurrency = 5.

With one annotation, you will get 5 consumers, each getting 2 partitions from each topic.

If you have two topics, the same thread is used to process 2 partitions from each.

Now, let's say records in topic1 take much longer to process than those from topic2. Records from topic2 could sit "behind" those from topic1. In that case, you might prefer to configure a separate listener container for each topic.

For low volume applications, one listener with multiple topics will be ok.

It all depends on your requirements.

By the way, you can put multiple `@KafkaListener` annotations on the same method; each one will create its own listener container.